# PowerShell: svn st and German umlauts

Tags: powershell, svn, encoding

I am using Windows PowerShell 4.0 on Windows 8.1 x64 with SVN binaries from TortoiseSVN 1.8.8.

Calling `svn st` displays

`!       Blähbauchß.txt`

However piping it like `svn st | where { $_ -match "\!\s*(.*)" }` displays

`!       Bl�hbauch�.txt`

This seems to be an encoding problem. It becomes relevant when I try to use the matches with `svn add` or `svn rm`. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'll delete this if it is off base here but are you running this in console or ISE? Try the other one to see if is different

Comment: @Matt: Running this in ISE makes it work as expected! Any ideas on how I can transfer this to the console?

Comment: It did. I added `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)` to the script and now it works. Thanks!